# xpath assertion in soapui not working

Tags: xpath, soapui

I am reach up to this using xpath- //ns1:GetAtomicWeightResponse/ns1:GetAtomicWeightResult[1] but how to reach upto    AtomicWeight.

```
<NewDataSet>
  <Table>
    <AtomicWeight>12.0115</AtomicWeight>
  </Table>
</NewDataSet>
```

Here , I am not able to get value of `AutomicWeight` from table `XML`.

**EDIT: Based on the comments from OP**, adding the xml in the question.

```
<soap:Envelope
    xmlns:soap="schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
    xmlns:xsi="w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:xsd="w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <soap:Body>
        <GetAtomicWeightResponse
            xmlns="webserviceX.NET">
            <GetAtomicWeightResult>
                <![CDATA[<NewDataSet><Table><AtomicWeight>12.0115</AtomicWeight></Table></NewDataSet>]]>
            </GetAtomicWeightResult>
        </GetAtomicWeightResponse>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Comment: Have you posed the correct xml data? Because, your xpath referring to something else. Are you using Property Transfer test step to retrieve?

Comment: <soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
   <soap:Body>
      <GetAtomicWeightResponse xmlns="http://www.webserviceX.NET">
         <GetAtomicWeightResult><![CDATA[<NewDataSet>
  <Table>
    <AtomicWeight>12.0115</AtomicWeight>
  </Table>
</NewDataSet>]]></GetAtomicWeightResult>
      </GetAtomicWeightResponse>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>

Comment: this is xml data

Answer (score 0):

Please use below `xpath`

```
//NewDataSet/Table/AtomicWeight
```

EDIT: Based on OP's data

Since, the data originally mentioned by you is in `cdata` that is why you were not able to get that value.

You can use below Groovy Script:

```
def xml = """<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <soap:Body>
        <GetAtomicWeightResponse xmlns="webserviceX.NET">
            <GetAtomicWeightResult><![CDATA[<NewDataSet><Table><AtomicWeight>12.0115</AtomicWeight></Table></NewDataSet>]]></GetAtomicWeightResult>
        </GetAtomicWeightResponse>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>"""
def getData = { data, element -> new XmlSlurper().parseText(data).'**'.find{it.name() == element} }
def atomicWeight = getData((getData(xml, 'GetAtomicWeightResult') as String).trim(), 'AtomicWeight').text()
log.info atomicWeight
```

Or you can quickly try online <kbd>[Demo](http://groovyconsole.appspot.com/script/5134543275163648)</kbd>

If you are using it in SoapUI's test case, you do not have to add an additional Groovy Test step to get that value. Instead add the `Script Assertion` to the same request step (where you get that response) with below code(processing is same, but you do not have to use fixed xml, instead a dynamic response can be used).

**Script Assertion**

```
assert context.response, 'Response is empty or null'

def getData = { data, element -> new XmlSlurper().parseText(data).'**'.find{it.name() == element} }
def atomicWeight = getData((getData(context.response, 'GetAtomicWeightResult') as String).trim(), 'AtomicWeight').text()
log.info atomicWeight
```

Comment: <soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
   <soap:Body>
      <GetAtomicWeightResponse xmlns="http://www.webserviceX.NET">
         <GetAtomicWeightResult><![CDATA[<NewDataSet>
  <Table>
    <AtomicWeight>12.0115</AtomicWeight>
  </Table>
</NewDataSet>]]></GetAtomicWeightResult>
      </GetAtomicWeightResponse>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>

Comment: please tell me for getting atomic weight

Answer (score 0):

Consider Following response in your soap XML

```
   <soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
   <soap:Body>
      <ConversionRateResponse xmlns="http://www.webserviceX.NET/">
         <ConversionRateResult>1505.7</ConversionRateResult>
      </ConversionRateResponse>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Xpath would be

```
declare namespace ns1='http://www.webserviceX.NET/';
//ns1:ConversionRateResponse[1]/ns1:ConversionRateResult[1]
```

Comment: <soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
   <soap:Body>
      <GetAtomicWeightResponse xmlns="http://www.webserviceX.NET">
         <GetAtomicWeightResult><![CDATA[<NewDataSet>
  <Table>
    <AtomicWeight>12.0115</AtomicWeight>
  </Table>
</NewDataSet>]]></GetAtomicWeightResult>
      </GetAtomicWeightResponse>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>

Comment: declare namespace soap='schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/';
declare namespace ns1='webserviceX.NET';
//soap:Envelope[1]/soap:Body[1]/ns1:GetAtomicWeightResponse[1]/ns1:GetAtomicWeightResult[1]

Comment: i ma not able to enter inside table tag